# What is the principal 12th root of one?

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $w$ be the principal 12th root of 1. What is $w$, and what are the real and complex parts of the following:

1. $w w^∗$      (* = complex conjugate)
2. $w^9$

Comment: What is $w$? And do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: @sami Does $w9$ mean $w^9$? Does $w\ast$ mean the complex conjugate of $w$?

Comment: @Sami I changed the formatting to TeX, which is the preferred format here. If you take a look at the edit by clicking the edit timestamp, I think you can pick it up rather quickly.

Comment: Thanks I was didn't know how to use it before.

Answer (score 1):

If you have learned about principal roots of 1, you almost certainly know that they all lie on the unit circle, and you have probably have seen [de Moivre's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) and [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Using one or both of them, you can find the real and imaginary parts of whatever power of $w$ that you like.

The one with the conjugate appears to be even easier. If $w=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$, what's the conjugate, and what is the product? Work it out!

Comment: I've done a question on this the conjugate is cos(θ)-isin(θ) and the product is 1, but I don't know what principal root means, my lecturer hasn't explained this.

Comment: Does it mean the positive root, so the positive root of 1 is 1 and the 12th positive root of 1 is 1 also?

Comment: $\omega$ is a principal 12th root of unity if and only if all other 12th roots of unity are powers of $\omega$.  So, for example, $e^{2\pi i/12}$ is a principal 12th root of unity, but $e^{4\pi i/12}$ is not.

Comment: @AlistairSavage That's a good definition for the *primitive* 12th root of unity, but I think the *principal* one is usually the first primitive root you reach going counterclockwise from $1$. Reading this post and Alistair's, does that clear things up, Sami?

Comment: @rschwieb: Yes, you're right.  I confused principle with primitive.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of principal root of unity is probably just $e^{2\pi i/12}$. As to the questions mentioned:

i) All roots of unity lie on the unit circle and so does $w$. What does this tell you about the length of $w$ and thus about $ww^*$?

ii) If $w$ is a 12th root of unity, $(w^3)^4=1$, so $w^3$ is a fourth root of unity. It shouldn't be too hard to conclude what $w^9 = (w^3)^3$ is from there.